# How do I compute a compact bit vector representing a predicate's result on each element of `ndarray`?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, image-processing, bitvector

I have an RGB image as an `ndarray` and want to compute a compact abstraction of it as a bit vector where each element indicates if the pixel is closer to white. (There is no need to dipslay this bitvector)

I looked at the references and figured out some functions. But so far I only found an easy way to have an `ndarray` of booleans (which is 8 times more redundant than my intention).
Is there a direct and efficient way to achieve what I want?

What I have so far:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Grayer than `128` counts as black, otherwise white
gray2bw = np.vectorize(lambda n: n < 128)

# Abstract an RGB image into black/white
def rgb2bw(image_rgb):
    return gray2bw(cv2.cvtColor(image_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY))
```

Comment: You should know your `gray2bw` is very inefficient. Just use `array < n` directly on an array and it will be vectorized. Using

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga!

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.bitwise.html -- I guess do `packbits` on the result. However, depending on your usecase, the memory savings may well be outweighed by impracticality of such representation.